# Color toolbar in CKEditor in Xpages (skins?)

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

I am using the dojo attributes in the RichTextControl in an Xpage (running Domino 9.0.0). Have everything just as I want it EXCEPT I cannot get the toolbar to appear in color.

In [this](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/CKEditor_in_XPages_in_NotesDomino_8.5.2) web page from IBM the toolbars are in color, and look so much better.

How do I get color toolbars?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is no CKEditor toolbar *in color* out of the box in Notes 9 anymore.

The toolbar icons are defined in a skin. You can find all installed skins on Domino server at `<server-directory>\data\domino\html\ckeditor\skins`.

Look for a skin of your choice at [ckeditor.com/addons/skins/all](http://ckeditor.com/addons/skins/all). Toolbar icons are in color in skins like "[Office 2013](http://ckeditor.com/addon/office2013)" or "[Moono Color](http://ckeditor.com/addon/moonocolor)". Click the Download button there and copy the folder from zip file into `<server-directory>\data\domino\html\ckeditor\skins`.

Link to the new skin with a Dojo property:

[image]

```
 <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
     <xp:dojoAttribute
        name="skin"
        value="office2013">
     </xp:dojoAttribute>
 </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
```

Comment: I have tried the above process with new skin which I have downloaded from "http://ckeditor.com/addon/kama" but the browser console log says "Cannot set property 'name' of undefined" in skin.js of kama folder.